# Group concat result is not exact

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-concat

I am using a GROUP_CONCAT() to display multiple category's but i am not getting an exact result. for table join i am using an IN() clause please help me on this.

> The query only displays a single category. in database category id store  like 2,5,8

```
$sql = "SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR ',') as cname, s.name as sname
        FROM course u        
        INNER JOIN category c ON c.id IN (u.category_id) 
        INNER JOIN status s ON s.id = u.status_id
        WHERE u.is_deleted = 0 AND u.id = $id $app
        LIMIT 1";
```

I want multiple categories from the category table.

Comment: For `GROUP_CONCAT()` to work you need to `GROUP BY` something. In your case you seem to want to `GROUP BY u.category_id`.

Comment: @KIKO Software: This is not true. Without `GROUP BY`, all records are assumed to be one group (at least for `mysql`). And that is the reason, that e.g. `count(*)` without `GROUP BY` works too.

Comment: @Wiimm I was reacting to the problem at hand. But you're right, it can be read as a general advice. My mistake.

Comment: *"Without GROUP BY, all records are assumed to be one group that e.g. count(*) without GROUP BY works too. "* @Wiimm  KiKO Software is right, in this case you need to use GROUP BY as the topicstarter is mixing aggregate columns with a aggregate one it's a SQL standard even.. it's is also mentioned in the MySQL [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) no exceptions not even in MySQL.. You are just plain wrong with that statement in this case while it's true without other non aggregate  columns in the query you can use aggregate  functions without using `GROUP BY`

Comment: "For GROUP_CONCAT() to work you need to GROUP BY something." is a general advise and not related to the question. And I wanted to clear this sentence.

Comment: 'IN (u.category_id) ' worries me is u.category_id a string containing many values by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

group_concat is an aggregation function and for the correct use of these functions when you need also column not aggrefated  require   the GROUP BY clause and the column name use for the aggregation level

```
    SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR ',') as cname, s.name as sname
    FROM course u        
    INNER JOIN category c ON c.id IN (u.category_id) 
    INNER JOIN status s ON s.id = u.status_id
    WHERE u.is_deleted = 0 AND u.id = $id $app
    GROUP BY s.name
    ORDER BY s.name 
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Similar comment as above: Without `GROUP BY`, all records are assumed to be one group (at least for `mysql`). And that is the reason, that e.g. `count(*)` without `GROUP BY` works too. So `GROUP_CONCAT()` works without `GROUP BY` too.

Comment: @Wiimm   this happen (by default) for mysql version < 5.7 but in these case for the not grouped by columns the result is unpredictable   for others version  mysql raise and error

Comment: You first sentence tells, that aggregation functions generally work only correct if using `group by`. And that is wrong. Example: `select count(*) n_user, sum(login_count) n_logins from user` : 2 aggregation functions without `group by` in a meaningful select.

Comment: the `LIMIT 1` would require a `ORDER BY` on atleast a primary or unique column otherwise the results are non deterministic (random) as SQL tables/resultsets are by SQL definition **orderless**

Comment: @RaymondNijland   correct order by added but  with group by should produce a default order by based on group by column s .. any way add also  a bried  suggestion for the use of group  by  .

Comment: *"group by should produce a defualt order by based on group by coulmn "* not annymore @scaisEdge als trusting on implict sorting on GROUP BY was offically deprecated since MySQL 5.7 and removed in MySQL 8.0

Comment: @RaymondNijland   . ok  (he had escaped me)   ..  thanks for suggestion  ,.. anyway  order by is present  now

Comment: A manual quote and link for completeness *"In MySQL, GROUP BY is used for sorting, so the server may also apply ORDER BY optimizations to grouping. **However, relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting is deprecated**"* see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html) but it was deprecated since MySQL 5.6 not MySQL 5.7 i was close..

Answer (score 0):

I used group by and order by but not working for me.

i think problem in "INNER JOIN category c ON c.id IN (u.category_id)" line if i pass "2,6,8" in place of u.category_id in IN() Clause its working fine.

please look at this.

Answer (score 0):

In first code if i use custom id in IN() clause working fine for me

$sql = "SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR '
') as cname, s.name as sname
        FROM course u
        INNER JOIN category c ON c.id IN (3,1,9) 
        INNER JOIN status s ON s.id = u.status_id
        WHERE u.is_deleted = 0 AND u.id = $id $app
        LIMIT 1";

if i use 'u.category_id' in IN() clause query retrieve only one category

$sql = "SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR '
') as cname, s.name as sname
        FROM course u
        INNER JOIN category c ON c.id IN (u.category_id) 
        INNER JOIN status s ON s.id = u.status_id
        WHERE u.is_deleted = 0 AND u.id = $id $app
        LIMIT 1";

I want to use IN (u.category_id) clause in query to retrieve correct result.